# Overloading operator for set

Tags: c++, stl, stdset

I am using a std::set to implement a specific algorithm.  The set had duplicates in it, so I assume I had to overload the operator. The overload looks like this.

```
class Vec3f {
    ...

    bool operator () ( const Vector3f& v0, const Vector3f& v1 ) const {
    float epsilon = 1e-7;
    return ((v1[0] - v0[0]) > epsilon) &&  ((v1[1] - v0[1]) > epsilon) && ((v1[2] - v0[2]) > epsilon);
}       ...


"Vec3f.h"

int main(){
    ...
    std::set<Vec3f,Vec3f> visited;
    ...
}
```

I overloaded it so I could use the < operator needed in std::set.  This function returns true if v0 < v1 to some margin.  It removes the duplicates, but it also removes valid values in the set.  I know my set is supposed have to 12 Vec3fs.  With the duplicates, it has 24 Vec3fs.  With my comparison function, it only has 3 Vec3f.  I considered using absolute difference, but that violates strict weak ordering criterion.  My question is: how do I write the comparison function to remove duplicates and keepd only the unique items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have it now, every component in `v0` needs to be less than every component in `v1`. This is not a strict weak ordering.  You should check one component at a time. Only checking subsequent components if the component you are currently checking is equal. Also, you should drop the epsilon. While that's useful for checking equivalence of results of floating point calculations, it is not useful for ordering, because it too violates strict weak ordering. The easiest way to do this is to use `operator<` for `std::tuple`

```
return std::tie(v0[0], v0[1], v0[2]) < std::tie(v1[0], v1[1], v1[2]);
```

Otherwise, if you want to implement this manually, it's something like this:

```
if (v0[0] < v1[0]) return true;
if (v0[0] > v1[0]) return false;
if (v0[1] < v1[1]) return true;
if (v0[1] > v1[1]) return false;
if (v0[2] < v1[2]) return true;
if (v0[2] > v1[2]) return false;
return false;
```

Comment: Nice usage of `std::tie` to test for lexicographical order, although I'm pretty sure in this case the design itself is flawed, and one shouldn't try to order 3D vectors

Comment: @vsoftco: Sometimes it's useful to be able to order things in some way, even if the ordering criteria are completely arbitrary. Just for the purpose of searching if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::abs` to compare the difference from `epsilon`, like

```
if(std::abs(v1[0]-v0[1]) > epsilon && ...){...} // not zero
```

Otherwise you may get negative results 
which will always be smaller than your `epsilon`, and the norm test will fail.

PS: in general it is a bad idea to try to order vectors, as there is no intuitive mathematical oredering, and you may get into whole lots of weird and counterintuitive situations.

Comment: I tried doing that but that violates strict weak and causes a runtime error.

Comment: @TringVu ahh ok, I see, you cannot order vectors by norm, like you cannot introduce a maninful ordering on the complex numbers. You should think maybe about a different ordering. You can e.g. compare first the absolute value, then the angle, but again, mathematically it doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you simply want to use a set, not necessarily an implementation of a set which requires an ordering. You might consider using `std::unordered_set`, which doesn't require you to define an ordering, just hash/equality functions.